# Automapper Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I have four entities Organization and Address ..for the sake of brevity I have omitted all but the properties in question in my entities and viewmodels

```
public class Organization : VersionedAuditableEntityWithTypedId<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
{
    //Organization related properties are in here

    /// <summary>
    /// Organization Address
    /// </summary>
    [NotNull]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address : AuditableEntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
   // Address related properties are in here

    /// <summary>
    /// Region/State
    /// </summary>
    [NotNull]
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}

public class Country : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of country
    /// </summary>
    [DomainSignature, Length(Max = 50), NotNullNotEmpty, SelectListItemDisplay, SelectListItemValue]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Region : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of region
    /// </summary>
    [Length(Max = 50), NotNullNotEmpty, SelectListItemDisplay,SelectListItemValue]
    public  virtual string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Country
    /// </summary>
    [NotNull]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1721", Justification = "Common naming for type descriptions")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I have two view models

1. EditOrganizationViewModel
2. EditAddressViewModel

Within my EditOrganizationViewModel I have the following property

```
public class EditOrganizationViewModel
{

 /// <summary>
 /// Organization address
 /// </summary>
 public EditAddressViewModel Address { get; set; }

}
```

My EditAddressViewModel has a list of countries

```
public class EditAddressViewModel

{

/// <summary>
/// List of countries
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

}
```

My countries property does not map to anything in my address entity but is needed to display a list of countries and it popluated in my service layer.

I perform mapping once in my application as so...

Once for the EditAddressViewModel...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, EditAddressViewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForAddress1, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForAddress2, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForAddress3, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForAddressType, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForCity, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForCountry, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForPostcode, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForRegion, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.Types, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.Countries, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.Regions, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Region.Country.Id))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Region, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Region.Id))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type.Id))
Mapper.CreateMap<EditAddressViewModel, Address>();
```

and once for the EditOrganizationViewModel..

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Organization, EditOrganizationViewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForOrganizationName, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.LabelForTeamSport, opt => opt.Ignore())
.AfterMap(
(organization, viewModel) =>
MapListItemToViewModel(organization.Phones, viewModel.Phone,
p => p.Type.Name == Resources.BusinessPhone))
.AfterMap(
(organization, viewModel) =>
MapListItemToViewModel(organization.Phones, viewModel.Fax,
p => p.Type.Name == Resources.FaxPhone)) 
.AfterMap(
(organization, viewModel) =>
MapListItemToViewModel(organization.EmailAddresses, viewModel.EmailAddress,
p => p.Type.Name == Resources.PrimaryEmailAddress));
```

I build my view model as below

```
public EditOrganizationViewModel CreateOrganizationFormViewModel()
{
        // Create the organization view model
        var viewModel = new EditOrganizationViewModel();

        // Load the organization and bind to view model
        var organization = _organizationRepository.FindAll().FirstOrDefault();

        if (organization == null) organization = new Organization();

         // Business Address
        viewModel.Address =
            AddressManagementService.Instance.CreateEditAddressViewModel(Resources.BusinessAddress);

   **At this point my countries list is populated**

   // Map the organization to the view model
      Mapper.Map(organization, viewModel);

  **My countries property is now null after Mapper.Map is called**
}
```

The problem arises when I call Mapper.Map(organization, viewModel). The countries list is now null. I am not sure how setup my mapping configurations to preserve my list of coutries. I have tried using a valueresolver but it only gets called if the address of the organization is not null. I would hate to have to really flatten my organizationviewmodel and include the address information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

if the or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either of 2 things should work...

1. for that field in the mapping, instead of `Ignore()` try `UseDestinationValue()`
2. populate the country list after the map is executed (reverse the order of the last 2 lines of your function)

Comment: UseDestinationValue() worked perfectly! I added this maping as well 
.ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Address != null))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address))
Thx!